# SSIS Error "Cannot convert between Unicode and non-Unicode string data types" only on ETL server Windows Server 2016

Tags: ssis, oracle11g, etl, windows-server-2016

I'm facing an issue with an SSIS package I developed using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. On my local environment, everything runs smoothly. However, when I deploy it on our ETL server running Windows Server 2016 using an automated process provided by Microsoft through a pipeline, I encounter the following error: "Cannot convert between Unicode and non-Unicode string data types."

Additional details about the configuration and versions:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: 13.0.16000.28
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools: 13.0.1700.441
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC): 10.0.14393.6078
Microsoft MSXML: 3.0 6.0
Microsoft Internet Explorer: 9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework: 4.0.30319.42000
Operating System: 6.3.14393
Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard Version: 10.0.14393 Build 14393
ETL Development: Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition with targetServerVersion set to SQL Server 2016.

From my research, I've found that this error can typically arise when there's a mismatch between data types of sources and destinations in SSIS​1​. There are suggested solutions, such as using a Data Conversion Transformation or a Derived Column Transformation​2​.

Despite these proposed solutions, I find it puzzling that I only encounter this error on the server and not on my local machine. Has anyone faced a similar issue? Could it be a specific server setting or a different SSIS version causing this problem? Or could it be related to the automated deployment process via the pipeline? I appreciate any insights or guidance.

Comment: This might be related to the default (or specified) code page setting of the machine. I have run into a similar issue importing data from Oracle to a Windows Server using SSIS. Eventually I figured out I needed to use a `SQL command` as my Oracle Source Data Access Mode, and then in the query I had to explicitly convert from the Oracle server's codepage to the Windows one. Here's what that called looked like in my case: `CONVERT(d."ColumnX",''AL32UTF8'',''WE8MSWIN1252'')`. If you need more info, I can write up a full answer.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this insight. I encountered a similar process while working with data transformations between Oracle and SSIS. Your information regarding the explicit conversion between the Oracle server's codepage to the Windows one was particularly helpful. The use of CONVERT(d."ColumnX", ''AL32UTF8'', ''WE8MSWIN1252'') was the crucial piece I needed. I appreciate the detailed information you provided; it greatly assisted in resolving my issues.